# Is there any way to replace variables in an array with Python 3? Making a Battleship game for my HW

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I am making a Battleship game, and I need to replace a variable in the array (a tilde ~ ) with an X when the user doesn't guess correctly. I also need to print the array afterward.
**EDIT: I am using Python 3.7.2.**

I tried using 
"X" = myArray[x,y]
where x and y are the variables in the array that need to be replaced. I also tried deleting and replacing but I don't know how to do that.

```
import random


def setupArray():
    arr = []
    for i in range(7):
        row = []
        for j in range(7):
            row.append("  "+'~')
    arr.append(row)
    return arr


def printArray(arr): 
    for val in range(1):
        line2 = ("   "+"1"+"\t"+"  "+"2"+"\t"+"  "+"3"+"\t"+"  "+"4"+"\t"+"  "+"5"+"\t"+"  "+"6"+"\t"+"  "+"7")
        line3 = "1"
        line4 = "2"
        line5 = "3"
        line6 = "4"
        line7 = "5"
        line8 = "6"
        line9 = "7" 
        for val2 in range(7):
            line3 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
            line4 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t") 
            line5 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
            line6 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
            line7 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
            line8 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
            line9 += (str(arr[val][val2])+"\t")
        print(line2)
        print(line3)
        print(line4)
        print(line5)
        print(line6)
        print(line7)
        print(line8)
        print(line9)

initBoard = setupArray()

printArray(initBoard)

row = random.randint(1,7)
column = random.randint(1,7)

def shiplocation(initBoard):
    ship = ((row),(column))

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)    

print("Welcome to Battleship! You have 7 guesses!")

q1 = (input("Row?")).title()
q2 = (input("Column?")).title()

y = 0

while q1 != row and q2 != column:
    print("Try Again.")
```

**This line is the area where I want to insert the code to mark the X.**

```
    printArray(initBoard) #prints the array
    q1 = (input("Row?")).title()
    q2 = (input("Column?")).title() 
    y += 1
    print("incorrect guesses: " + str(y))
    if y == 7:
        print("You ran out of guesses!")
        exit()
"""
if q1 == q1 and q2 == q2:
    print("Repeated Value")
"""


if q1 == row and q2 == column:
    print("You won!")
```

The expected output is when the user enters a row and column and is wrong, the variable of that array is marked with an "X" and the array is printed. Right now, I get errors when I try different things.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found two issues with the code before you reach the "X" issue. First off, your setupArray() function is off due to indentation for the loops. You want the `arr.append(row)` to be inside the `for` loop so that it adds in the row 7 times (otherwise it only does it once if it's outside the loop).

```
def setupArray():
    arr = []
    for i in range( 7 ):
        row = []
        for j in range( 7 ):
            row.append( "  " + '~' )
        arr.append( row )
    return arr
```

During debugging, it is useful to check each output variable to make sure it looks correct after running the function. In this case, printing out the `initBoard` variable would have revealed that it only has one row.

Second, the `printArray()` function is not looking at every row (it only looks at row 1). The reason is because you are reading in `arr[val][val2]` when `val` is always set to one (`range(1)`) while `val2` is correctly set to 1-7 (`range(7)`). An outline of how it should probably look:

```
def printArray( arr ):
    line2 = ...
    line3 = ...
    for val in range( 7 ):
        for val2 in range( 7 ):
            line2 += str( arr[0][val2] ) + "\t"
            ...
    print( line2 )
    ...
```

And finally, you are mostly correct on how to set the array to the "X" character. The only thing to be careful about is your `q1` and `q2` will be set to strings when you ask for user input, so you need to cast them to `int` in order to work:

```
initBoard[ int(q1)-1 ][ int(q2)-1 ] = '  X'
```

My only general hint is to print out each variable as the script runs to make sure everything is working properly. Also, be aware that the program currently breaks if the user does not put in a number when asked for input. You should do some exception handling (e.g. via the `try`/`except` syntax) to catch potential input problems.

**EDIT**: Because OP is still having problems, I'm pasting the whole updated code (with minimal updates) below for OP to review.

```
import random

def setupArray():
    arr = []
    for i in range(7):
        row = []
        for j in range(7):
            row.append("  "+'~')
        arr.append(row)
    return arr 

def printArray(arr): 
    line2 = ("   "+"1"+"\t"+"  "+"2"+"\t"+"  "+"3"+"\t"+"  "+"4"+"\t"+"  "+"5"+"\t"+"  "+"6"+"\t"+"  "+"7")
    line3 = "1" 
    line4 = "2" 
    line5 = "3" 
    line6 = "4" 
    line7 = "5" 
    line8 = "6" 
    line9 = "7" 
    for val2 in range(7):
        line3 += (str(arr[0][val2])+"\t")
        line4 += (str(arr[1][val2])+"\t") 
        line5 += (str(arr[2][val2])+"\t")
        line6 += (str(arr[3][val2])+"\t")
        line7 += (str(arr[4][val2])+"\t")
        line8 += (str(arr[5][val2])+"\t")
        line9 += (str(arr[6][val2])+"\t")
    print(line2)
    print(line3)
    print(line4)
    print(line5)
    print(line6)
    print(line7)
    print(line8)
    print(line9)
initBoard = setupArray()

printArray(initBoard)

row = random.randint(1,7)
column = random.randint(1,7)

def shiplocation(initBoard):
    ship = ((row),(column))

def random_row(board):
    return randint(0, len(board) - 1)

def random_col(board):
    return randint(0, len(board[0]) - 1)

print("Welcome to Battleship! You have 7 guesses!")

q1 = (input("Row?")).title()
q2 = (input("Column?")).title()

y = 0

while q1 != row and q2 != column:
    print("Try Again.")

    initBoard[ int(q1) - 1 ][ int( q2 ) - 1 ] = '  X'

    printArray(initBoard) #prints the array
    q1 = (input("Row?")).title()
    q2 = (input("Column?")).title()
    y += 1
    print("incorrect guesses: " + str(y))
    if y == 7:
        print("You ran out of guesses!")
        exit()
"""
if q1 == q1 and q2 == q2:
    print("Repeated Value")
"""

if q1 == row and q2 == column:
    print("You won!")
```

Comment: Thank you for fixing my 2 errors. I tried the int(q1) code but it still didn't work. Using your method, I figured out that the program gets the input numbers (q1 and q2) correctly. I am still clueless on how to mark the X.

Comment: Really? I made the changes according to what I wrote in my answer and it works properly. The only thing to mention is that python indices starting from 0, so it should technically be `int(q1)-1`... did you try a simple `print(initBoard)` after the "X" code to see what was happening after that line?

Comment: Thanks! When I changed the "for val in range(1)" to "for val in range(7)" there were too many rows of tildes. I changed it back to 1 and it was fine. I printed it using print(initBoard) and it did change to an X after all! Now there's something wrong with the printArray funciton. EDIT: I am using Python 3.7.2

Comment: http://prntscr.com/nqahj3 is what I have so far. For the "for val in range (7)" it would've given this output which I didn't want: http://prntscr.com/nqahv2 (it still wouldn't have printed an X if it was a 7)

Comment: Like I mentioned in the answer, your indentation was wrong. Look at the second block of code I put in my answer and use that. Not only do you have to change the `range(7)`, you also have to change where your `line=` and `print()` lines are placed. The python version shouldn't matter in this case... it's just that your program's logic is currently incorrect.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I realized that there was indenting and fixed it when I posted my second comment, and it still doesn't work. If you put row 1 and any column number, the whole column has an X in it. Screenshot: http://prntscr.com/nqcqnq

Comment: I added the whole code into my answer. Go ahead and try it. It works on my machine, and I'd be surprised if it doesn't work on any other standard system with python3. If it does work, compare it to your version to see what went wrong.

Comment: Thank you very much! Now it works. The reason it wasn't working for me was that I didn't sequentially do arr[0], arr[1], arr[2] but I only did arr[0] for the "for val2 in range (7)" loop.